# Does Docusaurus support renaming the 'docs' output folder?

Tags: docusaurus

I am currently evaluating using Docusaurus to generate a static web site. The site itself is not documentation focused, in fact, the site is not even computer or technology related. But as a techie myself, I want a CI and Git-powered publishing strategy for this web site.

Docusaurus uses Markdown for its page content (outside of custom React-based pages). However, when these Markdown pages are built, they are all placed in a top-level folder in the static site called `docs`. This folder naming doesn't really fit with the web site I want to produce.

There is a configuration setting for [`customDocsPath`](https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/site-config#customdocspath-string) but this only changes where the build looks for Markdown files, not the output path in the created site content.

I'm not a React developer, but aside from hacking away at the JavaScript in the build engine to search/replace instances of `docs`, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't currently support routes other than `/docs` - yet. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/Docusaurus/pull/914) that started back in August, but has been recently resurrected again. The PR is being reviewed and updated to allow more customizable routes.

Comment: I will update this question if and when that PR hits release, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In docusaurus 2 changing main docs folder is quite straightforward:

- rename `docs/` to `whatever/`
- add following to `docusaurus.config.js`

  ```
  presets: [
  [
    '@docusaurus/preset-classic', // should be already there
    {
      docs: {
        path: 'whatever',
        routeBasePath: 'whatever',
  // ...
  ```

Answer (score 1):

**As of Docusaurus 1.6, this is now implemented.** The [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/Docusaurus/pull/914) has been merged.

More details about this are found [in the site configuration](https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/site-config#docsurl-string).

Simply add the following to the `siteConfig` section in siteConfig.js:

```
const siteConfig = {
  title: 'My Awesome Site',
  docsUrl: '',
  // ...
};
```